# Embeddable FileOpenDialog

Tags: c#, .net, fileopendialog

I am looking for a control to be able to embed the functionality of the FileOpenDialog without the idea of using a modal dialog.  Does something like this exist already? (ideally within .Net 2.0 framework, C#).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't come across one, but I had to do something quite like what you're suggesting for my most recent project. What I did was make a way to select files in a dropdown from a `DataGridView`, but it can easily be adapted to what you're looking for.

There is [an excellent example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/FileSystemListView.aspx) about how to make a ListView that looks like the standard one in the FileOpenDialog. It uses a bit of P/Invoke to get the system image list and you might have to fiddle with it yourself to get it working right, but it's quite effective. I used this as a starting point and maybe it will help you start out in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I saw this example but this is something that I can only rate as a nice to have vs a must-have.  It would *almost* be worth doing since I could use it in other places as well but I can't justify it right now.

I did some more searching and didn't really run into anything like I was looking for.

Comment: I know what you mean. I bit the bullet because I needed to lock the user into a particular path and not let them change directories. That plus wanting to avoid the modal dialog was just enough to make it a necessity for me.